# Is there a way to get the request body with GET request?

Tags: java, jersey

I have this api:

```
@Path("test")
@GET
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Parameter performTest(Parameter in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

but the in always returns null.  I can change @GET to @POST and it works but I'm not really performing an create or update so using post seems odd.

Is there a way to get the body with a GET request with jersey?

Comment: No, because GET requests don't have a body.

Comment: So, the OP probably really wants the parameters on the GET, or the extra path?

Comment: @markspace are you talking about query or path parameters?  The issue with that is the Parameter will have a lot of data needed to run the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;DR* The correct solution is to use POST.

---

> "I can change @GET to @POST and it works but I'm not really performing an create or update so using post seems odd"

Why is that odd? POST is not limited to create/update operations.

The specification ([RFC 7231, section 4.3.3. POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)) says:

> The POST method requests that the target resource **process** the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.  For example, POST is used for the following functions (among others):
>
> - Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML form, to a data-handling process;
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, blog, or similar group of articles;
> - Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the origin server; and
> - Appending data to a resource's existing representation(s).

To paraphrase, POST means "here's some data, please process it for me".

Sure, "process" often means "store", as in create/update, but that is not the only way to process data.

In your case, "process" means "run test, using these parameters".